# Images /JS /css/html are not loading on chrome after migration from Weblogic 9 to Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, weblogic-10.x

We have recently migrated our Java application from Web logic 9 to Web logic 10.3.6 .
After loading the application on new URL we observed weird behavior in Google Chrome.

Problem : We are not able to see some images and some js files on interface. 
    E.g. Calendar , drop down etc images and some js files are not loading.If we refresh the page then more images are failed to load and so on resulting in plain app without css / js /images if you keep refeshing the page.
    However this issue is not consistent sometimes if you login multiple times then it load sometimes.`enter code here`

```
    E.g. Below logs I am able to see in Chrome console
    GET http:// someAppUrl /images/updown.gif net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
    GET http:// someAppUrl /blank.html net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
    GET http:// someAppUrl /images/dropdown.gif net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
    GET http:// someAppUrl /images/calendar.gif net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
    GET http:// someAppUrl /images/PopupCalendarLeft.gif net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
    GET http:// someAppUrl /images/PopupCalendarLeft.gif net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Chrome >> Network Tab below messages are coming:
    blank.html  (failed)    document        0 B 83 ms   
    dropdown.gif    (failed)        Other   0 B 70 ms   
    calendar.gif    (failed)        Other   0 B 72 ms
```

Looks like it is not even coming from server or tempered / blocked by network .Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you accessing WebLogic directly or through a fronting web server? Does Chrome load the image if you hit just that URL directly?

Comment: Try to load the page using an "incognito" window.  This should ignore existing cache.  My guess is that the browser is not getting things correctly.

Comment: @Brian : We are accessing Weblogic directly. No , if we hit the image url then also it is not loading giving the error as "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: @stdunbar : No luck with incognito mode as well.

Comment: What do you see in the WebLogic server's access.log?

Comment: @BrianOchs : Able to see HTTP 304 status for all the images/css that are not loaded. e.g. "GET /javascript/calendar.gif HTTP/1.1" 304

Comment: Do these URLs work if you try the HTTP request from the server machine itself basically ruling out any network setup?

Comment: @BrianOchs : I tried to disable my machine network proxy settings and changed it to localhost :8080. Then tried the Dev environment URL ,It Worked perfectly. So concluding that might be network proxy is creating any issue. Is it ?. How can I make it work with proxy settings , because all other apps are working perfectly with same proxy settings and we can't use the network without proxy , company policy.

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk with whoever manages the proxy server to add rules for this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching Oracle Middle ware Technology division. WE came to knew that this issue is because of Web logic .Oracle Web logic patch is required in order to fix this.